# One pointer for different types Fortran

Tags: pointers, fortran

I'am trying to write a procedure, which store addresses of user arrays for further processing. Problem is encapsulated in this test program:

```
program test_ptr
    real(4), target, allocatable :: i4(:,:)
    real(8), target, allocatable :: i8(:,:)
    real(4), pointer :: p(:,:)

    allocate(i4(2,2))
    allocate(i8(2,2))

    p => i4 ! ok
    p => i8 ! compile error
end
```

The compiler suggests making different pointers for different types.
But I don't want to create separate pointers for real(4) and real(8). I'am trying to make generic and compact solution and have one pointer for different types of data. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to store adresses I would be careful with polymorphism. Pointers to polymorphic variables often point to a descriptor which has different address than the real data. Consider using `type(c_ptr)` defined in the `iso_c_binding` module and the function `c_loc()` to obtain the address. It doesn't have to be used only for interfacing to C, there are couple of places where it is handy in pure Fortran.

Comment: Thank you, but i cant understand how it works. If `p = c_ptr(r4)`, then how can i get data under it (like `*p` in C)?

Comment: You then use the `c_f_pointer()` subroutine that sets a Fortran `pointer` to point to the data. You have to know the type, because it is not stored in the `c_ptr`.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to do this using (unlimited) polymorphism for `p`.

```
program test_ptr
  implicit none

  real(kind(0.)), target :: r4(2,2)
  real(kind(0d0)), target :: r8(2,2)

  class(*), pointer :: p(:,:)

  ! some assignments, etc.

  if (...some crazy condition...) then
    p => r4
  else
    p => r8
  end if

  select type (p)
    type is (real(kind(0.)))
      print *, p
    type is (real(kind(0d0)))
      print *, p
  end select

end program
```

Pay particular attention to the `select type` for when later using `p`.

Comment: See the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22723837/3157076) by Vladimir F if the _address_ (in the question) is the important part, more so than the _pointer_.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good idea, but my compiler said: 'Unlimited polymorphism at (1) not yet supported'.

Comment: @vovo That sounds like a gfortran error message.  4.8.2 (perhaps earlier, but I haven't checked when) does support this construct.